# Weight paint won't subtract!

Tags: weight-painting

Simply put all my brushes are doing the same thing, adding weight, no matter which setting I apply to the brush whether it be subtract or any other tool for that matter it only adds, this is making it very difficult to Weight paint, everyone I've asked who kind of knows the program doesn't know what to do.

Comment: When you are weight painting you are changing values in vertex groups. I had a similar issue once but managed to track down the culprits by looking at the vertex groups in the menu instead. Turned out that I had turned on some kind of mode where the mesh moved with the animation (which made weight painting buggy for me)

Comment: if I had previously deleted the vertex groups to try a data transfer weight paint would that effect it at all?

Comment: I think you can create vertex groups without weights. Not sure if they overwrite the ones that work though. But yes since it is the vertex groups that hold the information you need them, I think they show up in the right hand side menu in the viewport under some of the tabs there when you select a vertex. Maybe inside the new data tab too? I am still to rookie to know for sure.